# Pyserial communicatication with rs232 to usb in windows fail

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, pyserial

Hi I'm currently trying to communicate a Schunk gripper with my PC through Python. I used a PCAN-USB adapter to connect the device with my computer. I'm trying to use pyserial to communicate with the device in order to control it.

The problem is I dont know what's the name of the serial port by using pyserial, then I tried COM1 - COM6, also USB0, USB1, ..., but it returns me with the error:

> serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3':
>   FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.',
>   None, 2)

I tried this list_ports.comports() to get the name of the port but it shows me that there is no available port.

```html
import serial.tools.list_ports as list_ports

ports = list(list_ports.comports())
print(ports)
for p in ports:
    print(p)
```

The output is just [].

I would be very appreciate if anyone can help me!

Comment: I've never used this adapter but I doubt if it will work - CAN isn't the same as a serial (RS232-like) port.  When you plug in your adapter, does a COM port show up in the Windows Device Manager?  If it doesn't, then it's not working.

Comment: Hi Paul Thanks so much! I was thinking both CAN and RS232 are serial connection, then I also should be able to communicate with that by using pyserial? Another question is by using the adapter it's been changed to USB. Does that influence?

Comment: Again, I don't know this adapter but the ones I have used (USB-RS232) change the RS232 signals to USB signals at the hardware level.  But at the software level it still looks like an RS232 port.  So as far as programming is concerned, you pretend that you're talking to a real RS232 port (COM port in Windows-land).  The Windows Device Manager lists it as a COM port and pyserial will connect to it.